# How to edit an XML file with XStream?

Tags: xml, jsf, serialization, primefaces, xstream

Please find below my xml example :

```
<product>
<shoes brand="Nike" price="58 Euros" size="43" />
</product>
```

I am able to read the xml and to put the value of brand, price and size in 3 inputtext.

Now that I have the values in the the inputtext, I would like to be able to modify them and to generate a new xml file. The problem that I have is that when I generate the new xml displayed in a dialog with a inputextarea, it is still the initial values. Please find below my the full code :

index.xhtml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>XStream</title>
</h:head>
<h:body id="mybody">

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" id="mongrid">
        <h:outputLabel for="brand" value="Brand :" />
        <p:inputText id="brand" value="#{xmlreader.product.shoes.brand}"/>

        <h:outputLabel for="size" value="Size :" />
        <p:inputText  id="size" value="#{xmlreader.product.shoes.size}"/>

        <h:outputLabel for="price" value="Price :" />
        <p:inputText id="price" value="#{xmlreader.product.shoes.price}"/>

        <p:commandButton value="Generate XML" actionListener="#      {xmlreader.testDataModelGeneration()}" />
    </h:panelGrid>


     <h:form id="readxml" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <p:fileUpload id="upload" 
                          mode="advanced" 
                          required="true"  
                          cancelLabel="Cancel XML"
                          style="margin-top: 15px;"
                          requiredMessage="At least one file needs to be selected"
                          allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xml)$/"
                          invalidFileMessage="Not allowed file type" 
                          invalidSizeMessage="The file is too large (500 kb max)" 
                          uploadLabel="Process XML"
                          fileLimit="1"
                          fileLimitMessage="Please load one file at a time"
                          dragDropSupport="true"
                          label="Select XML" 
                          multiple="false"
                          fileUploadListener="#{xmlreader.allocation}"
                          sizeLimit="500000"
                          update=":mongrid"
                          />
     </h:form>

    <p:dialog id="dialogId"
              draggable="false" 
              dynamic="true" 
              header="XML Generated"
              widgetVar="dlgxml"
              width="1115"
              height="650"
              closable="true"
              modal="true"
              ><!-- Affichage du XML -->

        <h:form id="xml">

            <p:inputTextarea value="#{xmlreader.xmlFinal}" 
                             cols="115"
                             autoResize="true"
                             rows="20"
                             />

        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>

</h:body>
```

class Product :

```
@XStreamAlias("product")
public class Product implements Serializable{

private Shoes shoes;

public Product() {
}

public Product(String className) {
    shoes = new Shoes();
}

public Shoes getShoes() {
    return shoes;
}

public void setShoes(Shoes shoes) {
    this.shoes = shoes;
}

}
```

class shoes :

```
@XStreamAlias("shoes")
public class Shoes implements Serializable{

@XStreamAsAttribute
private String brand;

@XStreamAsAttribute
private String price;

@XStreamAsAttribute
private String size;

public Shoes() {
}

public Shoes(String brand, String price, String size) {
    this.brand = brand;
    this.price = price;
    this.size = size;
}

public String getBrand() {
    return brand;
}

public void setBrand(String brand) {
    this.brand = brand;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(String size) {
    this.size = size;
}

}
```

My the bean :

```
@SessionScoped
```

@ManagedBean(name="xmlreader")
public class XmlReader implements Serializable{

```
private Product product;
private Shoes shoes;

private String xmlFinal;
private StringBuilder xml;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.product = new Product();
    this.shoes = new Shoes();
    this.xml = new StringBuilder();
}

/*read an existing xml file and complete the input text*/
public void allocation(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException{

    this.xml = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(event.getFile().getInputstream(), "UTF-8"))) {
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                this.xml.append(line);
               // System.out.println(line);

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    try {
        XStream xstream = new XStream();

        xstream.processAnnotations(Product.class);
        xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
        Product resultat = (Product) xstream.fromXML(this.xml.toString());
        this.product = resultat;   

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/*Generate a new xml displayed in a dialog*/
public void testDataModelGeneration(){

    StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
    this.xmlFinal = new String();

    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);

    String xml2 = xstream.toXML(this.product);

    xml.append(xml2);
    this.xmlFinal = xml.toString();
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dlgxml').show();");
    //this.xmlFinal = xml.toString();

}

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public Shoes getShoes() {
    return shoes;
}

public void setShoes(Shoes shoes) {
    this.shoes = shoes;
}

public String getXmlFinal() {
    return xmlFinal;
}

public void setXmlFinal(String xmlFinal) {
    this.xmlFinal = xmlFinal;
}

public StringBuilder getXml() {
    return xml;
}

public void setXml(StringBuilder xml) {
    this.xml = xml;
}

}
```

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the input text values in the dialog, all you need to do is :

1) Put the inputtext in a form.
2) In the fileUpload, update this form by its id.

Many thanks to my colleague.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the dialog content in order to show the last changes from the Backing Bean.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":dialogId:contentId");
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dlgxml').show();");
```

Within XHtML, if you use a button to show the dialog, it needs to have an update attribute as bellow `update=":dialogId:contentId"`

Comment: Hello Proverbio and thank you for your reply. However I can't make it work. I have indeed a button to show the dialog but What is the content id ? is it the id of the inputtextarea ?

Comment: The content Id is the form id that you have in the dialog.

Comment: I tried but it is still not working. I am not sure if my problem is linked to the update of the dialog or to XStream.

Comment: I am trying with 2 different beans (one to read the xml and complete the input text, one to modify and generate the new xml), but still no success.